# Polymer: post iron-form with file upload using application/json contentType

Tags: html, ajax, web-services, polymer

We're trying to create a polymer based application, where in one part the user needs to upload a file to the web service that's handling all the data for the application.

All the examples we've found use a `FormData` object and reset the `iron-form` `contentType` field to cause `iron-form` to use the multi-part encoding. The webservice we use only accepts `application/json` so that's not really an option for us.

Ideally `iron-form` would just support a `<paper-input type="file">` and would load the file contents into the JSON field, but instead it just submits the file name. Maybe we need to implement the `pre-submit` event handler to read the file in JavaScript and set the relevant `iron-form` field to the text of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is [as specified in HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set):

> Otherwise, if the field element is an input element whose type
>   attribute is in the File Upload state, then for each file selected in
>   the input element, append an entry to the form data set with the name
>   as the name, the file (consisting of the name, the type, and the body)
>   as the value, and type as the type.

And in 4.10.22.8 (content-type `text/plain`):

> If the entry's type is "file", replace its value with the file's name
>   only.

Note that `application/json` is basically falling back to that.

So you will have to [read the file content in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) and put it into the JSON-payload yourself.

Comment: To submit the content of the file to a web-service, `readAsDataURL()` (linked from your answer) is not very usable - its mostly only appropriate to load media files as resources into the current page. We have implemented something like this, but used `readAsText()` instead.

Comment: That depends on the file type indeed. If you deal with text files, you are safe to work with `readAsText` while `readAsDataURL` works with both binary and text contents.